# Python: Sending SMS, Viber, Whatsapp for free

Tags: python, sms, whatsapp, viber

I am using Python 3.6.

I want to create project in which I will send particular users their own messages to their mobile numbers they leave on my website.

Is there any way I can send my messages to them for free, using SMS, Whatsapp or Viber? I have seen that Twilio isn't that cheap so I am looking for alternative solution.

Feel free to ask for more information.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no easy and free way to send mass messages. Otherwise they would be used for spamming. So you should pay some service or implement some tricky scheme which passes all bot protection. For whatsapp you can use https://pypi.org/project/webwhatsapi/

Comment: If you had the needed infrastructure for this task, would you share it with anyone for free?

Comment: @handras I wanted to do something like Telegram bot, but for Viber or Wapp to send messages to the specific user based on their mobile phones, don't have in mind to flood all people with millions of messages, something like a subscription for event system.

Answer (score 1):

@ldragicevic as Alex C wrote there is no free solutions, and there is cheap options for sending messages thougth Viber/Whatsup:

1. SendPulse - has example for Python - https://github.com/sendpulse/sendpulse-rest-api-python
2. Nexmo - Nexmo gives a lower price on SMS comparing to Twilio and they have a comprehensive library of examples written on Python, for example - https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/06/22/send-sms-messages-python-flask-dr/
3. BandWidth - from Nexmo to this Provider better according to - https://getvoip.com/blog/2016/06/01/twilio-alternatives/

Would be good to come to finish solution on Python. Choose what service is better for your current task.